# Cant post media to twitter api using nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, twitter, base64

Ok so I have an express server that I am using to post a picture to twitter using `media/upload`.

```
app.post('/api/post-picture', (req, res) =>{
  client.post('media/upload', {"media": data}, // Here lies the problem
  function(error, media, response) {
      if (!error) {
        client.post('statuses/update', {
          status: 'TEST PICTURE',
          media_ids: media.media_id_string
        }, function(error, tweet, response){
          if(!error){
            res.json({status: 'success'})
          }else{
            res.json({error: response})
          }
        })
      }else{
        res.json({error: response})
      }
    });
});
```

In my `req.body.media` I have a base64 encoded string that i am sending to my express server. I then take the base64 encoded image and I convert it back to raw binary data with:"

`var buf = Buffer.from(req.body.media, 'base64');`

And then I pass in that `buf` variable to

`client.post('media/upload', {"media": buf},`

For some weird reason twitters api says it cant recongize that media type:
Exact error message:

```
 "body": "{\"request\":\"\\/1.1\\/media\\/upload.json\",\"error\":\"media type unrecognized.\"}"
```

Their api says: "Media should be The raw binary file content being uploaded"

What am I doing wrong here?

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload.html

Working code snippet:

```js
app.post('/api/post-picture', (req, res) =>{
  // var encodedimage = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64')
  var buf = Buffer.from(req.body.media.toString(), 'base64');
  client.post('media/upload', {"media": buf}, 
  function(error, media, response) {
      if (!error) {
        client.post('statuses/update', {
          status: 'TEST PICTURE',
          media_ids: media.media_id_string
        }, function(error, tweet, response){
          if(!error){
            res.json({status: 'success'})
          }else{
            res.json({error: response})
          }
        })
      }else{
        res.json({error: response})
      }
    });
});
```

Twitters api also accepts a base64 encoded string but I also provide that and it also errors out on me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data:image/jpeg;base64` needs to be removed from the data in order for twitter to accept it, which is not documented anywhere on their api.

You can do this with

`var base64Data = encodedImage.replace(/^data:image\/jpg;base64,/, "");`